# Accessing pandas dataframe columns that are not in Index

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pull a few fields from the following nested json and write to a separate csv file:

```
{
  "AccountID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "LocationID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "CreatedBy": "string",
  "ModifiedBy": "string",
  "Created": "string",
  "Modified": "string",
  "LocationData": {
    "KeyFields": {},
    "DisplayPoint": {
      "Type": "Calculated",
      "Latitude": 0.0,
      "Longitude": 0.0,
      "VerificationType": "Client"
    },
    "BusinessStatus": "Open",
    "Status": "Active",
    "BusinessName": {
      "Name": "string",
      "LongName": "string",
      "Locale": "Not_set"
    },
    "BusinessDescription": {
      "Description": "string",
      "ShortDescription": "string",
      "LongDescription": "string"
    },
    "PrimaryAddress": {
      "AddressLine1": "string",
      "AddressLine2": "string",
      "AddressLine3": "string",
      "AddressLine4": "string",
      "AddressLine5": "string",
      "Neighborhood": "string",
      "Locality": "string",
      "Region": "string",
      "PostalCode": "string",
      "CountryCode": "string"
    },
    "PhoneNumbers": {
      "PrimaryPhoneNumber": "string",
      "Landline": "string",
      "Mobile": "string",
      "Fax": "string",
      "TollFree": "string"
    },
    "HoursOfOperationStructured": {
      "Su": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "Mo": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "Tu": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "We": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "Th": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "Fr": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "Sa": {
        "Ranges": [
          {
            "StartTime": "string",
            "EndTime": "string"
          }
        ],
        "State": "Open",
        "AdditionalInfo": "string"
      },
      "SpecialHours": [
        {
          "Date": "string",
          "Ranges": [
            {
              "StartTime": "string",
              "EndTime": "string"
            }
          ],
          "State": "Open",
          "AdditionalInfo": "string"
        }
      ]
    }  
}
```

I am able to use pandas and json_normalize to flatten the data. Then I am able to pull fields by referencing the fields I want like `df['LocationData.PrimaryAddress.Locality']`. This works for all the fields I need except the 'StartTime' and 'EndTime' ranges which throw a KeyError

When I try to extract the 'StartTime' or 'Endtime' ranges of any specific day by referencing it like so: `df['LocationData.HoursOfOperationStructured.Su.Ranges.StartTime']` ---- it returns with a

```
KeyError: "['LocationData.HoursOfOperationStructured.Su.Ranges.StartTime'] not in index"
```

How can I access the 'StartTime'/'EndTime' columns for all of the days from this file using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

The column `df['LocationData.HoursOfOperationStructured.Su.Ranges']` and all other similar columns have been "undernormalized": they contain single-element lists of dictionaries with the keys "StartTime" and "EndTime". You can convert these dictionary columns to "real" columns in a loop and then concatenate with the original dataframe:

```
ranges = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('.*Ranges.*')]
missing = [df[r].str[0].apply(pd.Series)\
                .rename(columns={'StartTime' : f"{r}.StartTime",
                                 'EndTime'   : f"{r}.EndTime"})
           for r in ranges]
df = df.join(pd.concat(missing, axis=1))
```

It's ugly, but it works.